# admin list_filter values depending on other filters

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Let's take a look at this example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    ...    

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books'...)
    ...

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='chapters' ...)
    ...
```

For the admin, lets configure `ChapterAdmin` like so:

```
class ChapterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('book__author', 'book',)
    ...
```

This gives nice filters by related `Author` and `Book`.

Here goes the question:

When user clicks on an `Author` in `book__author` filter, the results in main table get filtered accordingly. Good. But the `book` filter still lists all available `Books`, regardless of the `book_author` filter. Is there a way to make the `book` filter dependent of `book__author` filter such that when an `Author` is selected, only `Books` by that are related to the `Author` are listed in filter options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can use `SimpleListFilter` to do the job, since you have the request in the `lookups` method you can tell which author is selected and provide only a list of his books, more info in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter